# Valgrind is not showing line numbers despite of providing -g flag in make file

Tags: c, postgresql, valgrind

I have a `postgresql` extension shared library to test under valgrind. I have added the -g option in the make file which creates this shared library after compiling the functions involved in it.

```
CC = gcc
override CFLAGS += -g -Wall
```

After make and make install, I run make installcheck under `valgrind` server which tests my shared library through `sql` commands written in the test script. This is my `valgrind` command:

```
valgrind -s --suppressions=postgresql-11.2/src/tools/valgrind.supp --leak-check=full --trace-children=yes --track-origins=yes --read-var-info=yes postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data --config-file=/usr/local/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf
```

The output which I am getting from `valgrind` is :

```
==11903== Syscall param socketcall.sendto(msg) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==11903==    at 0x4E4EBAD: send (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.26.so)
==11903==    by 0x6AF914: pgstat_send.part.4 (in /usr/bin/postgres)
==11903==    by 0x6B2022: pgstat_report_stat (in /usr/bin/postgres)
==11903==    by 0x6B23AB: pgstat_beshutdown_hook (in /usr/bin/postgres)
==11903==    by 0x702894: shmem_exit (in /usr/bin/postgres)
==11903==    by 0x70290D: proc_exit_prepare (in /usr/bin/postgres)
==11903==    by 0x702987: proc_exit (in /usr/bin/postgres)
==11903==    by 0x722F0F: PostgresMain (in /usr/bin/postgres)
==11903==    by 0x6B9004: ServerLoop (in /usr/bin/postgres)
==11903==    by 0x6B9E35: PostmasterMain (in /usr/bin/postgres)
==11903==    by 0x47F051: main (in /usr/bin/postgres)
==11903==  Address 0x1ffeffe7dc is on thread 1's stack
==11903==  in frame #2, created by pgstat_report_stat (???:)
==11903==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==11903==    at 0x6B1ED0: pgstat_report_stat (in /usr/bin/postgres)

==11903== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11903==     in use at exit: 1,256,022 bytes in 437 blocks
==11903==   total heap usage: 1,287 allocs, 850 frees, 6,189,096 bytes allocated
==11903== 
==11903== 22 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 65 of 194
==11903==    at 0x4C2FDFB: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==11903==    by 0x5855BD9: strdup (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.26.so)
==11903==    by 0x6B9610: PostmasterMain (in /usr/bin/postgres)
==11903==    by 0x47F051: main (in /usr/bin/postgres)
==11903== 
==11903== 29 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 69 of 194
==11903==    at 0x4C2FDFB: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==11903==    by 0x5855BD9: strdup (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.26.so)
==11903==    by 0x85EFB4: set_pglocale_pgservice (in /usr/bin/postgres)
==11903==    by 0x47ECF4: main (in /usr/bin/postgres)
==11903==
```

As you can see, I am not getting proper line numbers in the stack trace. Why is that? What am I missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The `postgres` version which I am using is :

*PostgreSQL 11.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 7.2.1 20170915 (Red Hat 7.2.1-2), 64-bit*

Comment: So none of these functions were written by you.  They belong to Postgres, it wasn't built with -g.  Could be that Postgres has these bugs, could be that your extension destabilizes it too much.  Probably the latter.

Comment: So, am I suppossed to fix them or not ? Here I have shown you just 2 error messages but there are around 20 of such messages in which it is pointing out in main and specifying postgres functions in the stack trace. I am not sure whether to fix them or leave as it is.

Comment: @no_one Run Postgres under Valgrind **without** your extension, and see if it emits similar errors.  If it does, there may be a bug in Postgres, in which case you can file a bug report.  Note that the Postgres developers might feel that the uninitialized memory referred to by Valgrind doesn't matter. I'd personally argue otherwise as it pollutes the output from Valgrind and makes finding other problems harder.

Comment: The two definitely lost chunks could be consequences of PostgreSQL using `putenv()` instead of `setenv()` to set environment variables. If my guess is correct, `putenv()` is probably used to avoid portability problems; not all systems support `setenv()` even now.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thank you for your suggestion. I did the same and found that most of the errors, which I was getting, reappeared when I ran an inbuilt function of postgres in place of my extension's function, which clearly means that Postgres has already some unresolved bugs to fix.